# cambiar el valor de un numero en un archivo en c

Tags: c, archivo, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo que hacer un una función la cual al darle una clave, me muestre otro numero el cual seria el "dinero de la persona", después pedir ingresar un valor y al dinero sumarle lo que se acaba de ingresar, tendría que eliminar la clave y el dinero y volverlo a escribir o se puede sustituir en el mismo lugar.

````
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define numclientes 10
struct datos{
    char usuario[30];
    int ncuenta;
    int montototal;
    int bono;
    int nrad;
};
int main(){

  FILE *archi =fopen("dinero.txt","r");
    int monto;
    int nuevodinero;
    int nmonto;
    char nnumer[10];
    int i=0;
    struct datos clientes[numclientes];
    char apecomparar[15];
    char listaape[10];

     printf("cuenta:\n");
    scanf("%s",apecomparar);
    do{
    fscanf(archi,"%s",listaape);
    if(strcmp(apecomparar,listaape)==0){

    printf("encontrado\n");

    fscanf(archi,"%s",nnumer);

    break;

    }
    else{

    }
        }while(feof(archi)==0);
        scanf("%d",&monto);
    nmonto= atoi(nnumer);
    nuevodinero=monto+nmonto;
    printf("%d",nuevodinero);
  fclose(archi);
  archi =fopen("dinero.txt","a");
  fprintf(archi,"%d",nuevodinero);
  fclose(archi); 
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Estas en lo correcto, no hay forma de sustituir un caracter en un archivo, yo te recomendaria leer desde el inicio del archivo hasta dónde esta el número que deseas cambiar, todo esto mientras lo que lees lo escribes en otro archivo copia, escribas el nuevo dato en el archivo copia y continues leyendo y escribiendo hsata terminar el archivo

Comment: ok gracias entonces asi lo hare